# User name does not appear in log-in in Ubuntu 22.04 after making the account via Jupyterhub

Tags: ubuntu, jupyter, account, jupyterhub

I'm trying to enable JupyterHub to create an account in Ubuntu 22.04 when making a user account in it by setting ".LocalAuthenticator.create_system_users=True" as written in the guideline in "https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/getting-started/config-basics.html"

Doing this made the account as this:
[image]

However, the user name for the newly made accounts do not appear in the login user list like this - original user account appears, but newly made mlops_user1,2 don't appear:
[image]

What am I supposed to do to

1. make the user name appear in the log in
2. and to prevent the same situation in the future

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You link to the documentation doesn't look to go to the pertinent information. Shouldn't it be to https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/getting-started/authenticators-users-basics.html#use-localauthenticator-to-create-system-users. , which is `https://jupyterhub.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial/getting-started/authenticators-users-basics.html#use-localauthenticator-to-create-system-users` ?

Comment: @Wayne Thank you for correcting me. That's the page.